# What's the meaning of the 'had'?

Tags: meaning

Is this word, ‘had’ could be implying two ways, one is ‘owned’, the other ‘made’?

[example]
Dunno if he had enough human left in him to die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Had* has many uses, for example:

- Standalone verb indicating possession or ownership
- An auxiliary verb indicating a past action that has been completing

  In this sentence, I think *had* is used in the first sense. The sentence is also metaphorical and so `had enough human[ity?]` means owning not an object but displaying a certain quality, which perhaps the larger context makes clear.

Comment: I think you're right about possession. Perhaps the context is horror fiction where someone is turning into something else and the amount of human material in him is diminishing.

Comment: Horror fiction or graduate school?